# HTC one X Gallery Pics and videos are not visisble

Tags: htc-one-x, gallery

My HTC one x gallery pics and videos suddenly disappeared. I can see them in DCIM folder but not visible over the phone.

I restarted the device , clear the cache everything is done but no use. When I open gallery the message shows " No photos found.

Comment: Have you recently updated your phone? Because it could be an issue with the new firmware update of the HTC One X. My phone didn't have this problem, but I heard from some people that they lost their pictures too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable the app named "Media Storage" from App->Menu->Manage apps

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I can think of is this - download this app called [Rescan Media](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner) which simply forces Android to perform a re-scan of the SD-Card and pull in/update the internal media links to the images on the SD-Card itself, so that it will show up in the gallery.

By the sound of it, it looks as if (I'm not exactly 100% certain) that the media scanning is broken on your handset... or that the gallery is failing.

If the above fails to work, then perhaps a suggestion would be to try get a newer firmware or use an alternative ROM such as CyanogenMod/Stock vanilla Android...

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Gallery and on the top-right corner you will find a '*Menu*' button. Tap that and choose '*Show/hide albums*' option. In the new window that appears, Check '*Select All*' or '*All Photos*' and '*All Videos*' and tap on '*Save*'.

If you are still unable to find any pictures or videos in your gallery, follow @t0mm13b's answer. It will help.

**Note:** Selecting '*All Photos*' will show ***ALL*** pictures on your device. Even including the small bitmaps that applications '*in your SD Card*' use as resources!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Rescan Media application but did not work. Restarted the phone, still did not work. Then, I figured it out that the SD card came from an old Blackberry and some data was left behind. Thus, I formated the sd card with the computer (FAT) and put it back into the phone. Works like a dime! :)

Answer (score -2):

Download this app called Rescan Media and run this application within 2 min issue solved

Comment: How is this any different from (or better than) @t0mm13b's answer?